# How to Reassign Workflow Tasks in Workflow Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm beginner in SharePoint 2010. I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow that creates a task. The task has custom form and custom code will be executed when the form is submitted. But i would like to re-assigned current task to different user if the actual user cant submit their task.

I found the code at http://sharepoint.aspcode.net/view/635399286724222582137494/correct-way-to-reassign-workflow-tasks-in-visual-studio-wf. The code is following :

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        //SPUser Approver = workflowProperties.Web.AllUsers["To"];
                        int tid = onTaskChanged1_AfterProperties1.TaskItemId;
                        SPListItem currentTaskItem = workflowProperties.TaskList.GetItemById(tid);
                        string TaskApproval = (currentTaskItem["Approval"].ToString());
                        if (TaskApproval.Length > 0)
                        {
                            //workflowProperties.LogComment(TaskApproval, "The item was " + TaskApproval + " by " + Approver.Name);
                            if (TaskApproval == "Reassigned")
                            {
                                Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
                                ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = currentTaskItem["ReassignedTo"];
                                ht["ReassignedTo"] = null;
                                ht["Approval"] = string.Empty;
                                //currentTaskItem.SystemUpdate();
                                SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(currentTaskItem, ht, false);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //perform actions if item is not reassigned
                            }
                        }
```

I created two fields which is "Approval" and "ReassignedTo" in Task list. In the Approval Field I placed the value "Reassigned" and in the ReassignedTo field is the value of the user the task is being reassigned to.

but I got this Error :

> This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be
>   edited

This is the error that i found :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SNVw.jpg

How to rectify this problem? Is it necessary to pause the workflow first before executed the code?

Answer (score 0):

Terminate the workflow (because it really hangs and there’s not much you can do with it) and kick off a new one.

Now open the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell (PowerShell) and run the following (or similar code):

```
$s = Get-SPSite("http://intranet")
$w = $s.RootWeb
$i = $w.GetFile("http://intranet/Shared Documents/Instructions.txt").Item
$t = $i.Tasks[0]
$ht = new-object Hashtable
$ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask]::AlterTask($t, $ht, $false)
```

This WILL work and correctly finish the approval cycle in any of my tested environments.